# PHP Issue with using a temporary file for cache of content

Tags: php, caching, static

I have been working on creating a quick twitter widget for myself to re use, just something simple that caches the data from the public api. Since twitter only allows X requests for a certain time period  and I have been testing this on a shared host, Its very often that I run out of requests and twitter denies my request. Thus I check first whether my request is denied, before writing an updated cached file.

Unfortunately I seem to lose this file from time to time, as I often see the 'temp file not written' message. Which should only appear if the file doesn't exist.

Here is the full php function:

```
function getTweets($num)
{
    $cfile = sys_get_temp_dir().'/e1z'. $type . md5 ( 'something' );

    if (is_file ( $cfile ) == false) {
        $cfile_time = strtotime ( '1983-04-30 07:15:00' );
    } else {
        $cfile_time = filemtime ( $cfile );
    }    

    $difference = strtotime ( date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ) - $cfile_time;

    if ($difference >= 100) {

        $tags = array("created_at", "text", "screen_name", "profile_image_url"); // twitter names
        $local = array("time", "msg", "user", "image"); // local names

        $reader = new XMLReader();
        $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=boriskourt&include_rts=true&count=' . $num;

        $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
        if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'){

                if (is_file ( $cfile ) == true) {
                        $returner = file_get_contents ( $cfile );                   
                        touch ( $cfile );
                        file_put_contents ( $cfile, strval($returner) );
                        $returner = file_get_contents ( $cfile );
                        return  $returner;
                } else {
                        $returner = "<li><span>Temp file not written</span></li>";
                        return  $returner;
                }

        } else { 
            $reader->open($url);

            $i = 0;
            $k = 1;

            while ($i < $num)
            {
                $j = 0;

                while ($reader->read() && $j < 4) // run through each tweet
                {
                    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == $tags[$j])
                    {
                        while ($reader->read())
                        {
                            if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT && $j == 0)
                            {
                                if ($k) {
                                $tweets[$i][$local[$j]] = $reader->value;
                                $j++;
                                $k=0;}
                                else {$k=1;}
                                break;
                            }
                            else if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT)
                            {
                                $tweets[$i][$local[$j]] = $reader->value;
                                $j++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                $i++;
            }

            $returner = "";

            foreach ($tweets as $value) {
                if ($value[user] != 'fugataquintet') {
                    $returner .= '<li class="retweet">';
                } else {
                    $returner .= '<li>';
                }
                $messager = $value[msg];
                $messager = " ".preg_replace( "/(([[:alnum:]]+:\/\/)|www\.)([^[:space:]]*)"."([[:alnum:]#?\/&=])/i", "<a href=\"\\1\\3\\4\" target=\"_blank\">"."\\1\\3\\4</a>", $messager);
                $messager =  preg_replace( "/ +@([a-z0-9_]*) ?/i", " <a href=\"http://twitter.com/#!/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a> ", $messager);
                $messager = preg_replace( "/ +#([a-z0-9_]*) ?/i", " <a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a> ", $messager);
                $returner .= '<span>'.$messager.'</span><a class="datereplace" href="http://twitter.com/#!/fugataquintet" title="'.$value[time].'">'.$value[time].'</a></li>';
            }

            touch ( $cfile );
            file_put_contents ( $cfile, strval($returner) );
            return  $returner;    
        }    
    } else {    
        $returner = file_get_contents ( $cfile );
        return  $returner;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `$cfile` even exist? You're checking if it exists, but has it been created?

Comment: what is this > strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))

Comment: $cfile does not exist when that message fires, that is what I check for there. It does get created though, and if the file is not 'old' [ not >= 100 ] the script does pull directly from $cfile and displays the tweets properly. But it seems that something removes the file, ether outside the script or due to the way I create it. Is this some normal behavior?

Comment: @scuzzy : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @BorisKourt time() should be sufficient.

Comment: @BorisKourt: Why ask date() to format the time as a string just so you can turn around and parse that string back into a time value?  That's making unnecessary work for the computer...

Comment: Why are you doing that file_get_contents/strval/file_put_contents/file_get_contents sequence?  what does that accomplish?

Comment: Alright thanks, I will change that :) The main issue is more important right now though, if you have any ideas for that I'd love to hear them!

Comment: @Mark Reed, ah yes, sorry I left that in. I was testing to make sure that the file is set and that I can read it from there still. It is very backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted suffers from a classic race condition for dealing with filesystems; one description lives at OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_Access_Race_Condition:_TOCTOU

As you are on a shared host, someone else may be periodically cleaning out the system temp directory. If you need a more permanent cache, try saving the file somewhere else.

The following code checks if the file exists, and if not, creates it, and keeps it open. This prevents the file from being deleted by another process (eg temp directory emptier) until the function exits.

```
<? //PHP 5.4+
function getTweets($num){
    //This will keep the file open, 
    //so that the file cannot be deleted during when this function executes.
    $file = new \SplFileObject(
        \sys_get_temp_dir() . '/e1z' . $type . \sha1('something'),
        'c+' //
    );

    if ($file->getSize() !== 0 && 
        \time() - $file->getMTime() < 100)
    {
        $contents = '';
        foreach($file as $line){
            $contents .= $line;
        }
        return $contents;
    }

    //Get data from twitter
    //Write it to $file
    //return data from twitter
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this simplified version of your expiration checking?

```
if(is_file($cfile) == false OR filemtime($cfile) < time() - 100)
{
  // fetch here
}
else
{
  // load from cache here
}
```

Edit: I've also made a cut down version that fetches

```
function CacheTweetsXML($num)
{
  $cfile = sys_get_temp_dir().'/e1z'. $type . md5 ( 'something' );
  if(is_file($cfile) == false OR filemtime($cfile) < time() - 100)
  {
    // fetch here
    $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=boriskourt&include_rts=true&count=' . $num;
    if($xml = @file_get_contents($url) and @file_put_contents($cfile,$xml))
    {
      return $xml;
    }
    elseif(is_file($cfile)) // can't load, return from cache
    {
      return file_get_contents($cfile);
    }
    else // cant load and isn't cached, return false
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  else // load from cache here
  {
    return file_get_contents($cfile);
  }
}
```

also don't forget to clean up $type

Comment: I will modify my code accordingly, but the main issue has been clarified above if interested. Thank you! Note: I can't vote up yet, need 15 rep. But I will once I get there.